# How to change select's option based on a selected option's value?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have `select` tag below:

```html
<select name="selID" id="selID" data-mini="true"">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Tithes</option>
    <option value="2">Offering</option>
    <option value="3">Designated</option>
    <option class="selOptAddMore" value="0">Add More...</option>
</select>
```

I want to change value when one of the options is selected except for "Add More..."

Sorry I'm a newbie. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind providing your html/javascript snippet and also a clearer explanation on what you're expecting so we can help you out?

Comment: Change the value of what?

Comment: when the i select one of the values, that will be displayed. what i need is to only respond change of values for Tithes, Offering and Designated.

Comment: Still not getting you

Comment: Confused!! what actually you want ..

Comment: i am very sorry if i am not clear. The code I provided is a dropdown with 4 options. Tithes, Offering, Designated, and Add More.. If i choose for example offering, it will be the one to be selected. what i need is to only respond change of values for Tithes, Offering and Designated but not Add More...

Comment: By respond you mean like an alert/console.log of the selected value ??

Comment: yes. a console.log. thank you for your patience with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

The HTML:

```
<body>
    Result: <p id="result"></p>

    <select name="selID" id="selID" data-mini="true" onchange="test()">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Tithes</option>
        <option value="2">Offering</option>
        <option value="3">Designated</option>
        <option class="selOptAddMore" value="0">Add More...</option>
    </select>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

*test.js:*

```
    function test() {
        let listVal = document.getElementById("selID").value;
        if (listVal != "0") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = listVal;
        }
        else {
            listVal = 1; // this is value for "Tithes"
            document.getElementById("selID").value = listVal;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = listVal;
       }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this. will just replace console.log instead of the p tag for the result. but is there a way that the "Add More..." value will not be selected. Instead the original selected value (which is Tithes based on my provided html code). thanks

Comment: I changed the code; I think this is what you wanted.